# Growing memory usage when rendering animation

Tags: animation, memory-management

I'm using Blender 2.77a with Windows 10 64 bit on a 8 GB RAM PC and AMD R9 390 graphic card with driver 16.4.1.

When GPU rendering a very simple animation (350 faces, 150 frames, single PNG files) local memory usage in Task Manager goes from 80 MB to over 2 GB after the first 20 frames so I need to stop, close, run again Blender and start rendering from the last rendered frame. It works with CPU.

I read that Blender doesn't store frames in memory so I would check some rendering setting before fill in a bug report because of a memory leak.

Any idea ? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why is that a problem? Unused RAM is wasted RAM. It's probably just trying to cache things.

Comment: Yes is a problem because Windows shows a low memory error message and crashes so I cannot leave Blender unattended.

Comment: Oh, but that's not related to the RAM usage; my guess is that's a timeout thing where the graphics card hasn't responded for, like, 2 seconds, so windows just kills the program. You should be able to google the exact message, and find a fix rather easily. And post your error message.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your file. I'm able to render it with no issues at all (Windows 10 64 bit).  Try reloading factory settings. (File->Load Factory Settings). Long time ago I had a similar issue with the memory for the GPU not being released properly, and reinstalling and clearing the settings was the only way to work. Note also that you are using a AMD R9... there's been a lot of issues reported with those... That might be part of your problem. Try rendering on CPU...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnY9B.gif